# Можно добавить библиотеки внутрь Jar файла?

Tags: java, maven, lib

Java проект использует сторонние библиотеки, подключаю их как *maven* зависимости через *IDEA*.

При запуске сборки в *target* появляется собранный *app.jar* и папка *lib* с библиотеками. В манифесте эти библиотеки прописаны.

Можно ли запихнуть эти библиотеки внутрь моего *app.jar*?

Comment: Да, используйте maven-shade-plugin. Он создаст *-shaded.jar со всеми зависимостями. Вроде еще был assembly plugin, но я им не пользовался.

Comment: @Etki спасибо вам, maven-shade-plugin все сделал как надо)

Comment: @Etki не хотите ли оформить как ответ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin хочу. Но для этого его надо подробно расписать :\

Comment: @Etki найдите время, комьюнити оценит)

Comment: все зависит от того с какой целью вам это надо:
1) я знаю что мне это надо - смотрите ответы других участников
2) я думаю что мне это надо - смотрите пункт "вам это не надо"
3) вам это не надо - поменяйте тип прожекта на "war" для главного артефакта таким образом он будет включать в себя свой код + все зависимости

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще есть как минимум два плагина, который позволяют собрать `jar` файл с зависимостями.

Это [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) и [Maven Assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). Как использовать каждый из этих плагинов можно найти по ссылкам на официальную документацию. Там же есть подробное описание когда, какой из них использовать (по мне они в большинстве случаем равнозначны, но иногда один из них подходит лучше).

Answer (score 0):

Из комментарий **Etki**

Да, используйте **maven-shade-plugin*. Он создаст `*-shaded.jar` со всеми зависимостями. Вроде еще был `assembly plugin`, но я им не пользовался.

Etki 17 сен в 17:26